# Kotlin reflection on Anonymous object using kotlin-reflect

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I am receiving a json object in which there is a property I don't know the name of at compile time.

The name of the property is stored in a variable.

Since the name of the property may vary the JSON is parsed as an Anonymous object.

Is it possible to read the value of the property using reflection using the name stored in the variable ?

I tried with code resembling this:
`jsonResponse::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == variableName }`
with no success.

```java
val decodedToken = JWT(jwtString)
decodedToken.getClaim("useful_claim").asObject(Any::class.java)?.let {
  // Get the property that matches the variable name 
  val reflectProp = res::class.memberProperties.find { it.name == BuildConfig.VARIABLE_NAME }
  // Check that the property was found and exists
  if (reflectProp is KMutableProperty<*>) {
    (reflectProp.getter.call(res, BuildConfig.VARIABLE_NAME) as? List<*>)?.let {
      // Return it as a list of existing MyClass
      return it.filterIsInstance<MyClass>()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? Reflection for this seems inappropriate, there should likely be a way to parse JSON into a map-like structure, which you could easily inspect/read at runtime without reflection.

Comment: The JSON is parsed from a JWT using com.auth0.android.jwt.JWT

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're using? AFAICT JWT provides a way to access a map of claims. How do you get your anonymous object in the first place?

Comment: I updated the post to include my code

Comment: I don't know this JWT library, but I think you misunderstand one important thing. `Any` does not have any properties. If you deserialize JSON into `Any` then most probably all data is just ignored, it is not stored in the resulting object. Try to deserialize the data to some dedicated `JsonObject` or similarly named class (read the documentation) or alternatively, into `Map<String, Any>` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comments made by [@Joffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114482/kotlin-reflection-on-anonymous-object-using-kotlin-reflect?noredirect=1#comment123943749_70114482) and [@broot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70114482/kotlin-reflection-on-anonymous-object-using-kotlin-reflect?noredirect=1#comment123944338_70114482) I tried without the JWT library.

Here is the code:

```java
// Parcelable classes
@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class JwtCustomResponse(
    // This maps the variable name from the buildconfig on a known field name that can be used later
    @field:Json(name = BuildConfig.VARIABLE_NAME) val appResourceAccess: MyCustomClass? = MyCustomClass()
) : Parcelable


@Parcelize
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class JWTBody(
    @field:Json(name = "resource_access") val resourceAccess: JwtCustomResponse? = JwtCustomResponse(),
) : Parcelable

// Custom JWT deserializer
object JWTUtils {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun decoded(JWTEncoded: String): JWTBody {
        val split = JWTEncoded.trim().split(".")
        val mAdapt = moshi.adapter(JWTBody::class.java)
        return mAdapt.fromJson(getJson(split[1])) ?: JWTBody()
    }

    @Throws(UnsupportedEncodingException::class)
    private fun getJson(strEncoded: String): String {
        val decodedBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(strEncoded, Base64.URL_SAFE)
        return String(decodedBytes, charset("UTF-8"))
    }
}

// JWT passed to the Utils
val decoded = JWTUtils.decoded(jwtString)
```